# Cannot run common module in xlam file as macro is disabled

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, add-in

VBA / Excel - 2007

I want to create one (possibly many) .xlam file(s) to hold common modules accessible across projects. Along the way I have received a number of errors but through the creation of a "mickey-mouse" scenario I have boiled it down to one error condition (as shown in actual result):-

I have seen several problems reported here related to this which in the end have either not been answered or the solution has not quite hit the mark

As a precursor to this I was able to put my common module into another .xlsm project and successfully execute it by using a reference to that called project. However it would be preferable not to create a workbook for the sole purpose of housing common modules

'Caller VBAProject (Caller.xlsm):

```
Public Sub Caller()
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0

    '*** Error in line below***
    Application.Run "C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Common.xlam!Test", i

End Sub
```

'Called Test (Common.xlam) -- different project, obviously

```
Function Test(ByRef i As Integer) As Boolean

    If i = 0 Then
        Test = False
    Else
        Test = True
    End If

End Function
```

## Actual Result

Run-time error '1004':

Cannot run the macro

'C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\Mirosoft\AddIns\Common.xlam!Test'
The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may
be disabled.

## Steps Undertaken (in Excel Options)

1. Trust Center

   a) Macro Settings
            -- both i) and ii) (at different times)

   ```
     i) Disabled all macros with notification

    ii) Enabled all macros

   iii) set Trust access to the VBA project object model
   ```

   b) Add-ins -- left as default ie no option ticked

   c) Trusted Locations -- have added the following
       C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\
2. Add-Ins

   As an Active Application Add-in I have

   ```
   C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Common.xlam
   ```

Can anybody please tell me what I might have missed?

Comment: Is `Mirosoft` (in your error message) a type only in your question or also in your code?

Comment: Rather than running it from a different excel file, you can just import module at runtime. This means your module is local than and gives you access to any UDF's within the module. It also means that any updates to the module will filter down to anyone using a file that imports **the module**. Do a search for "Import module at runtime VBA". Don't forget to check if module already exists before importing it into your file

Comment: Typically the format is *Application.Run "Module.Macro"*, and it just looks like you'er calling a macro (*Test*), but not the module it's within.  Have you attempted to add the Module name?

Comment: Side thing... if you have a specific file you keep all of your masters in, you can mirror those files to the appropriate folder, e.g. *robocopy c:\documents\source %appdata%\microsoft\excel\xlstart /mir*

Comment: Everyone, thank you for your comments. This is the first chance I've had to look at this problem since I posted it. I will endeavour to take away what you've said and work through your responses

Comment: FunThomas: That is indeed a typo. It should read have read: 'C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\Mirosoft\AddIns\Common.xlam!Test'

Comment: Zac: Thanks !! I managed to get that to work. I exported the file as Common.bas. I then imported it to  the same project and renamed the new module as _Common_. I changed the code from Application.Run "C:\Users\IT\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Common.xlam!Test", i      to         b = Common.Test(i)     where b is a boolean and it worked. the only problem I still have is that within the Trust Center I still have to "Enable all macros..." but that is another issue (possibly)

Comment: Cyril: To avoid confusion I changed the function name to _Tester_  and my calling code to       `...\Common.xlam!Module1.Tester", i`; unfortunately to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

So just to summarise I **don't** have a direct answer to my question thus far, that is how to avoid the 1004 error when calling a macro within a .xlam file. However, I do have a more than adequate alternative which is to import the common file into a different module within the same project. What I'm realising is that as I write this it isn't an import at runtime or late binding as **Zac** implied. I'm not sure I'm too worried though (at least at the moment).